# How do I prove $\blacktriangle ABC$ is a right triangle?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

**The vertices of the triangle are $A(-3, 5)$, $B(4,7)$, $C(-1,-2)$**.

Apparently I'm getting this question all wrong?

To find if it's a right triangle, I know that I have to see if line $AB$ is perpendicular to line $BC$, so I find the slope of both lines:

$AB$: $m ~{= (7 - 5 )/ (4 + 3)\\= 2 / 7,}$

$BC$: $m ~{= (-2 - 7) / (-1 - 4) \\= -9 / -5 \\ = 9 / 5.}$

The slopes are not a negative reciprocal, so they're not perpendicular.

Is that right?

Comment: Oh, look at the other angles.  *One of them* is a right angle.

Comment: and the slope of AC is -7/2. So AC is perp to AB; i.e. angle A is a right angle.

Answer (score 2):

> vertices $A(-3, 5), \,B(4,7), \,C(-1,-2)$

Alternative hint:  one of the following is the sum of the other two:

$$
|AB|^2=(4+3)^2+(7-5)^2=53 \\
|BC|^2=(-1-4)^2+(-2-7)^2=106 \\
|AC|^2=(-1+3)^2+(-2-5)^2=53
$$

Answer (score 1):

I deduced that the vertices for your triangle have the following coordinates:

- vertex $A$ is located at $(-3,5)$,
- vertex $B$ is located at $(4,7)$, and
- vertex $C$ is located at $(-1,-2)$.

Then the slope of the line passing through the points $A$ and $B$ is 
$$
m_{AB} = \frac{7-5}{4+3} = \frac{2}{7} 
$$ 
while the slope of the line passing through the points $A$ and $C$ is 
$$
m_{AC} = \frac{-2-5}{-1+3} = -\frac{7}{2}. 
$$
So you do have a right triangle.

Comment: so, you can compare any two of the given lines? i just assumed that line AB and BC are legs and compared them

Comment: @ineedgr10mathhelp The first thing I did is to figure out where the vertices of the triangle are located on the $xy$-plane. Then by inspection, it appeared that the line passing through the points $A$ and $B$ is perpendicular to the line passing through the points $A$ and $C$. Thus I checked the slope for these two lines and as you mentioned above, the slopes are negative reciprocal of each other. So it is indeed a right triangle.

Comment: @ineedgr10mathhelp: **Never assume.** :)

Comment: @ineedgr10mathhelp By the way, the only time the idea of using the negative reciprocity of the slopes of any two of the lines passing through two of the vertices of a triangle does not work is when one of the lines is a horizontal line while the other is a vertical line. For example, if your triangle has vertices $A$ at $(0,1)$, $B$ at $(0,0)$, and $C$ at $(1,0)$, then use the law of cosines $|AB|^2+|BC|^2-2|AB||BC|\cos \theta=|AC|^2$, where $|AB|$ is the length of the line segment between $A$ and $B$, to show that $\theta$ must be $90^{\circ}$, where $\theta$ is the angle $\angle ABC$.

Answer (score 1):

It not say that our triangle can not be a right-angled triangle.

Try calculate the following slops.

$m_{AB}$ and $m_{AC}$.

Answer (score 1):

We can use Pythagoras' Theorem to find the lengths of the sides, since we have the coordinates of the vertices:

$$|AB|^2 = 7^2 + 2^2 = 53$$
$$|BC|^2 = 5^2 + 9^2 = 106$$
$$|CA|^2 = 2^2 + 7^2 = 53$$

and then we can use the [**converse** of Pythagoras' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem#Converse) (which is perhaps less well-known). We have a triangle in which the sum of the squares on two sides ($53 + 53$) equals the square on the third side ($106$); therefore this triangle contains a right angle (specifically, between $AB$ and $CA$, so at $A$).

Comment: which is just the good old law of cosines....